# No resolution options in NVidia X Server and Gnome display settings

Tags: unity, nvidia, gnome, display-resolution

I have a strange problem with my new Dell 5520. It seems like the NVidia settings utility does not allow me to change resolution. I tried several different proprietary drivers - no luck, also I know that it works perfectly fine on my other laptops. On the other hand, I can do it through utility available in Unity. Screenshots are attached. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image: NVidia settings utility]

[image: Unity display settings]

Comment: How big is the xscreen0 size?  virtual size in use would seem to indicate that Nvidia thinks the physical size is smaller.  Did you try "Detect Displays"?

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you for your comment! Sure, I did. The last screenshot shows the actual size.

Comment: Click on the X screen 0 menu item to see what size  Nvidia thinks.

Comment: @ubfan1 The only thing I see when I click on it is "X screen  0",  nothing else.

Comment: You should see a screen with Screen Number,Display Name, Dimensions,... and the dimensions are what's of interest.  If not seen, no screen is set up?  Try running without any /etc/X11/xorg.,conf file and see if that helps.  Post the xorg.conf file if not.

Comment: Dell Precision 5520 has a NVIDIA Quadro M1200. That means `nvidia-375` only: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/118290/en-us

Comment: @MichaelBay That is what I use